# Access external native functions using JNI

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, abi

I have a small doubt regarding native library access using `NDK`.

1. Is it possible to access native functions in the library using `JNI`? I have a library built completely on `C++`, is it possible to load that external library and write `JNI` to communicate with functions in the library?
2. If not is it possible to embed that `JNI class` within the library and communicate with it from `Android` activity?

Comment: (1) Yes provided you write a `C` wrapper for it.  JNI is a `C` API. You really need to read the NDK docs and build one of the many sample programs that come with the NDK.

Comment: how can i access method within native library from jni?? @RichardCritten

Comment: thanks i got a sample in nativeCodec sample in googleNDK(https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-codec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this sample code:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo025

There, you have a sample code that wraps C++ code inside JNI wrapper.

Unfortunately, all you can do (inside JNI) is to call native function.

Have fun with JNI!

Comment: .oOo. Thanks! Have fun with JNI :) .oOo.